# How do I configure a static HTML page for different environments?

Tags: html, gulp, nunjucks

I'm using Nunjucks for HTML templating and gulp to compile the page. It's just a static one page site but now I found I need to have different values for analytics and such for each environment. What's the best way to do this?

I was thinking about having a config json file and writing different gulp tasks for each environment to change the values but I'd like to see if there's a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Nunjucks, you can specify [`if` statement blocks](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#if). You can also specify assets paths using variables.

```
{% if env == "dev" %}
  <div>dev code</div>
  <img src="{{img_path}}placeholder.png" />
{% else %}
  <div>prod code</div>
  <img src="{{img_path}}placeholder.png" />
{% endif %}
```

You can create a config file for your environments.

```
// file: config.js
module.exports = {
  'dev': {
    env: 'dev',
    img_path: '/path/to/dev/img/'
  },
  'prod': {
    env: 'prod',
    img_path: '/path/to/prod/img/'
  }
};
```

Then you could create separate tasks for dev and prod.

```
const nunjucks = require('gulp-nunjucks');
var Config = require('config');

gulp.task('dev', function() {
  return gulp.src('index.html')
    .pipe(nunjucks.compile(Config.envs.dev))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

gulp.task('prod', function() {
  return gulp.src('index.html')
    .pipe(nunjucks.compile(Config.envs.prod))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Comment: This is good for blocks of code but I also have a case where all the image paths need to be adjusted for each environment.

Comment: @user3832805 I've included image paths in the answer. If you don't want to create separate tasks, you can also specify NODE_ENV and use process.env.NODE_ENV to determine the environment in your build process. I'm assuming you're just running it locally on your machine now.